# Problema com função de agregação, usando CreateQuery do Hibernate

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, query, group-by

- Em uma Embalagem, um fkEmbalagem referencia ao 'pai', a embalagem maior.
  EX: digamos que dentro de uma embalagem B cabem 10 embalagens A.
  Um registro de embalagem A vai ter no seu fkEmbalagem a embalagem B na qual ela estará inserida.
- Há uma query que busca quantas embalagens de tipo B existem com menos de x embalagens de tipo A associadas a elas.

`.createQuery("SELECT e.fkEmbalagem FROM Embalagem e "
+ "WHERE e.fkEmbalagem IS NOT NULL " 
+ "AND e.fkTipoEmbalagem.id = :tipo "
+ "GROUP BY e.fkEmbalagem "
+ "HAVING COUNT(e.id) < : x")`

A query reclama:
Column Embalagem.ID is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Até onde sei, quando a query possui função de agregação, só posso colocar no select algo que esteja ou na própria função de agregação ou no group by. O e.fkEmbalagem está no group by, então não sei porque dá errado.

UPDATE:

Percebi que o problema é quando passa para o SQL, pois o que seria um e.fkEmbalagem no hibernate vira uma série de coisas quando passa pro select no SQL (ex: embalagem.id, embalagem.data_alteração, etc) e ele reclama porque estes itens que estão no select deveriam também estar na função de agregação ou no group by. Mas o objeto que representa isso tudo está.
Como faço para resolver isso? Preciso retornar o objeto inteiro!

Se fizer apenas :

`SELECT e.fkEmbalagem.id
[...]
GOUP BY e.fkEmbalagem.id`

funciona, mas aí estou pegando apenas ID. Eu queria o objeto todo.